# Species on a planet scale

Tags: evolution, space, life

Because of the huge size of the universe and being that we occupy a tiny bit of it, you could assert that in some parts of the universe (just so happens that not in ours) there is a vast number of intelligent species occupying few planets each.

Working in that scale, can it be possible, that the entire species (no matter how intelligent it is) is just like an organism, that is, it is born, develops and eventually die? And even, could you assert that there exists some kind of natural selection acting on a species' phenotype as species are fighting for resources, not on a planet, but interplanetary?

Comment: Alternate question: Given everything you have been taught in science class and researched on your own time... can you think of a single reason why you couldn't have such planets?  (If you can't, then you have your answer.  If you can think of a reason, it'd be useful for WorldBuilders to know why you think it might not be possible)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be two questions:

1. Can an entire species be an organism?
2. Could natural selection occur on an interplanetary scale for such an organism when competing for resourcing across multiple planets?

Answers:

1. Yes. - This is simply an extension of Social Organism theory on a much vaster scale. (And believe me, once you get the theory in your head, you can actually feel it happening around you, which is definitely a way to either be motivated towards your fellow citizens, or feel terribly insignificant!)
2. Almost certainly yes. - Even for an organism (species) that operates on reason and democracy that survives and continues to survive and thrive is doing so through natural selection. It is simply that natural selection is favouring the organism that can reason and has democracy under a certain set of conditions. - As far as I am able to ascertain, there is no other mechanism for evolution on any scale other than natural selection.